# Solr 4 - Group results by 'yes' or 'no'

Tags: solr, lucene

Using Solr 4 I have documents that have a field for 'carry case'. The values for 'carry case' can be

```
None
Small
Medium
Large
```

From within Solr is it possible for me to group the results together to be 'Yes' if the 'carry case' value is 'Small' , 'Medium' , 'Large' or 'No' if the value is 'None'.

So my results would look like:

```
Yes (23)
No (41)
```

And clicking on 'Yes' would then return all docs with 'Small , medium or large' carry cases.

I've taken a look at [Field Collcapsing](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) but couldn't see a way of achieving what I need . The closest I could get to was something like:

```
select?q=*%3A*&group=true&group.field=carrycase&group.query=(carrycase:medium%20OR%20carrycase:Small)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for performance reasons I would build a new column (usecarrycase) and feed yes/no values to this field based on the above rule. 
How do you index documents into your solr? can you easily extend that?

Comment: Right now I'm just using the DataImportHandler to import directly from the DB. Adding a new column though would work.